# How to change the cursor image in Java AWT and/or Swing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, cursor, awt

I'm making a simple graphics editor (i.e a *paint program*). I am not planning on anything fancy, but I do want my program to change the mouse cursor to something like a "+" or an "O" when it enters the Paint Panel. like in Photoshop or GIMP. 
[image: Gimp Cursor]

How would I do this? I can't find anything in AWT / Swing threads on how to change the mouse cursor.

Comment: [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1840__Cursor.htm) you will find a good tutorial to work with Cursors in Java Swing.

Comment: +1 for your stackoverflow question in your stackoverflow question

Comment: ...questionception! (someone had to say it)

Comment: Related, for JavaFX: [How to create custom cursor in javaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894882/how-to-create-custom-cursor-in-javafx), [JavaFX custom css cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168501/javafx-custom-css-cursor)

Answer (score 9):

Just in case someone wants something more "fancy" than any of the default cursors: it's possible to create a custom cursor (provided the Toolkit supports it) showing an arbitrary custom image. A crude (no shiny visuals) example:

```
    Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension dim = kit.getBestCursorSize(48, 48);
    BufferedImage buffered = GraphicsUtilities.createCompatibleTranslucentImage(dim.width, dim.height);
    Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, dim.width - 1, dim.height - 1);
    Graphics2D g = buffered.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.draw(circle);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    int centerX = (dim.width - 1) /2;
    int centerY = (dim.height - 1) / 2;
    g.drawLine(centerX, 0, centerX, dim.height - 1);
    g.drawLine(0, centerY, dim.height - 1, centerY);
    g.dispose();
    Cursor cursor = kit.createCustomCursor(buffered, new Point(centerX, centerY), "myCursor");
```

Comment: well, the question was about awt/swing, or not :)