# JavaFX custom css cursor

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am searching the web but i can't find how to set a custom cursor in javaFX with **css** , i know how to do it with `ImageCursor` like this:

[How to create custom cursor in javaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894882/how-to-create-custom-cursor-in-javafx)

but i use this line in `css` and not working:

```
setStyle("-fx-cursor:url('/images/pencil.png')");
```

Is there possible to create a costume one with `css`?

Comment: Have you tried `cursor: url(images/pencil.png), auto;` ... both with and without the first forward slash

Comment: @Perneel: Rolled back the edit replacing the `javafx` tag with the `javafx-8` tag, since there is no indication in the question whether it's specifically related to `javafx-2` or `javafx-8`. Please take care to not suggest any edit that may conflict with the authors intent. Also keeping the `javafx` tag would probably have been the better idea.

Comment: @fabian edited the tag .. i need it for javafx 8.

Comment: @LGSon javafx css is a little bit different that original css.I tried your option but not working.

Comment: @GoXr3Plus: Many things are done similarly in `javafx-8` and `javafx-2`. In this case the concepts should be the same for both. Nowadays the `javafx` tag is more or less used as a synonym for these javafx versions. Also keeping it probably makes your question easier to find and gets it more attention. The main reason for the rollback was the lack of any indication that the edit was justified(I may have missed some communication between you and the editor).BTW:IMHO it's never a good idea to add some info only in the tags.  This just seemed a exceptionally bad edit in a history of OK edits for P

Comment: It's really strange for me. Based on the CSS Reference Guide, "-fx-cursor" should accept standard "<url>", therefore your try should be correct. I've also tried it on a `Button`: with invalid URL nothing happens, with valid URL a `ClassCastException` has been thrown. I have also tried to use the resolved URL (getting from debugging the stack trace) in the java code like `button.setCursor(new ImageCursor(new Image("file:\\...")));` sucessfully.

Comment: @DVarga i put the image in the same package with the class and i used (-fx-cursor:url('pencil.png'))  and it doesn't work though..

Comment: @GoXr3Plus yes, that's what I am saying. I was only succesful if I've set the cursor in the Java code but not in the CSS file, however the resolved file path from CSS seems correct (as it is working when using it in Java). I am really curious now - for me at the moment it seems to be a bug (I hope someone will prove me the opposite:) ).

Comment: I have found a bug report on OpenJDK from last year about this, that is still unresolved: [fx-cursor doesn't render a ImageCursor using the provided URL](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089191)

Comment: It should be noted though, that the url is incorrect. Use ```getClass().getResource("/images/pencil.png").toExternalForm();``` to get the correct url.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee For setStyle(..) or you mean for ImageCursor class?Cause if you use it on setStyle() you get NullPointerException.

Comment: NPE (probably) means that the file does not exist. And I mean for ```setStyle```. You would use ```setStyle("-fx-cursor: url(" + imageURL + ");");```

Comment: @Jorn Vernee The image is in the same folder as the class using this setStyle("-fx-cursor:url('"+getClass().getResource("pencil.png").toExternalForm()+"');"); as you recomended is not working,NullPointerException.The image exists though.Have you tried it and it worked?

Comment: @Jorn Vernee Edit i know get java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Cursor

Comment: And that is the error the bug report is talking about ;). I did a bunch of debugging, and found that there is a converter to convert the css value to a ```Cursor``` object, which includes a case for a url. Setting the cursor to anything other than a url calls the converter, but with a url the converter does not get called, and the raw path (string) is set as the cursor value. It seems that, if you want to use a custom cursor, using the ```ImageCursor``` way is the only way for now, because of this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Updated

It came to my attention that the original sample using

```
setStyle("-fx-cursor:url('/images/pencil.png')");
```

which fire an exception, appears to be a bug:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089191

Still, if to assign a custom cursor the CSS way, it needs to be done as shown below.

---

Original answer

When using custom [CSS cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor), a non-URL fallback (one or more of the other values) **must** be at the end of the fallback list, i.e. `auto`, so your code need to look like this:

```
//---------------------------------------------- ↓
setStyle("-fx-cursor:url('/images/pencil.png'),auto");
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you linked to a [Web Cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) in your answer, but provide CSS for a [JavaFX Cursor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Cursor.html)—they, unfortunately, aren't the same animal. I'm curious if you got this to work, but have my doubts because of the bug mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: When I tried your code, I got a `ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Cursor`

Comment: @BradTurek -- As the comment about the bug came 5 hours after my answer, I haven't seen it. Regarding "Web Cursor", OP asked about that, and if to set a cursor the CSS way, which one appear can't because of this bug, one need to do it in the way I show, hence I referred to it.

Comment: @BradTurek -- I updated my answer, clarifying it, and hopefully it is now good enough for you to retract your downvote.