# -fx-cursor: url("CCursor.png"); Gives java.lang.String cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Cursor

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

---

---

EDIT: Thanks to ZhenyaM for showing me [this](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/05/tutorial-change-default-cursor-javafx/)

i used this in the Main() class that intellij gives you with a javafx project:

Image image = new Image("batman.png");  //pass in the image path
scene.setCursor(new ImageCursor(image));

---

---

I want to make a custom cursor for my JavaFX + FXML + CSS game. But

```css
-fx-cursor: url("CCursor.png");
```

gives me

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Cursor
```

I've tried using `primaryStage.getScene().setCoursor(cursorImage);` (yes, I did try it with the cursor image).

(also the `-fx-background-image: url("Logo.png");` does work)

Css:

```css
* {
    -fx-base: #363636;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semibold";
    -fx-font-size: 18;
}
.root{
    -fx-cursor: url("CCursor.png");
    -fx-background-image: url("Logo.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
}
```

I expected my cursor to turn into a 32x32 png I have, but instead it gave me this

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javafx.scene.Cursor
```

Comment: not full answer, but for start your could use [this one](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/05/tutorial-change-default-cursor-javafx/)

Comment: @ZhenyaM that fixed the issue, thank you! also im new to stackoverflow, how do you close a question?

Comment: @SWCreeperKing, not at all. howevere I would glad if you'll upvote my comment=))

Comment: There appears to be [a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089191) that breaks custom cursors for CSS, by the way. That's why applying an `ImageCursor` in your code worked when passing a url in CSS did not. See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168501/javafx-custom-css-cursor#comment63770972_38168501) by Jorn Vernee.